# how is catalog_product_index_price / customer_group price beeing generated?

Tags: magento2, product-prices

Does anybody know where magento get's the data for the `price` field in the table catalog_product_index_price ?

If I have 4 customer groups with ids `0 / 1 / 2 / 3` in the mentioned table I have 4 entries for price per product. That's usually the standard price.

If I define extended pricing for a `customer_group` then that appears in the field "tier_price".

Reason for my question is if I can use that table for individual `customer_group` pricing without using tier_price. But where in the database is the price for a certain customer_group stored which then is used from magento for generating the `catalog_product_index_price` ???

Thanks for feedback in advance,
Marc